# swift how to get self.tableView.reloadTable() when UITableViewController is not class type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a normal view controller with a table view inside, so the class is just a normal `UIViewController`, therefor I am unable to call `self.tableView` with this.

I have an asynchronous call to create an array of Aircraft objects that is taken from an online database, but that is only completed after the table cells are initially loaded. I am trying to update the table cells after this asynchronous call is completed, but am unsure how to do so.

I do the async call in `viewDidLaod()`. Here is my current code that only displays the loading tags since the update has not taken place for the aircraft array.

```
class AircraftViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let log = Logger( id: String(AircraftViewController.self) )
let dvc = DownloadViewController()
var aircraftArr = [Aircraft]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dvc.getMobileSystemOverviewHTML {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.aircraftArr = self.dvc.aircraft
            self.log.debug("\n\n\n\n\n \(self.aircraftArr) \n\n\n\n\n")
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table View Delegate Methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AircraftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AircraftCell


    if indexPath.row < aircraftArr.count{
        let singleAircraft = aircraftArr[indexPath.row] as Aircraft
        cell.aircraft = singleAircraft
    } else {
        cell.aircraft = Aircraft(tailID: "Loading", aircraftSN: "Loading", Box_SN: "Loading")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the outlet of tableview like this

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

After that reload this tableview in your dispatch_async

```
dvc.getMobileSystemOverviewHTML {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.aircraftArr = self.dvc.aircraft
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.log.debug("\n\n\n\n\n \(self.aircraftArr) \n\n\n\n\n")
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It is giving me a nil while unwrapping error when I reach the self.tableView.reloadData(). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you bind the storyboard tableview with controller outlet?

Comment: I just had to link it to the actual storyboard, not just create it with that one line! Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Yes you have to link it. :)